# WFFM MVC add javascript onclick when Submit

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm currently trying to trigger dataLayer push events on submit for wffm mvc form. There are a couple of sources I've found and none of them has worked so far for MVC. The closest to what I could work with is combining what I've gathered with these two links [Sitecore WFFM: act on success](https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2016/07/sitecore-wffm-act-on-success.html) and [Trigger Google Analytics Events on Sitecore Web Forms](http://blog.petersondave.com/sitecore/wffm/Trigger-Google-Analytics-Events-on-Sitecore-Web-Forms-for-Marketers-Submit-Actions/)

Currently, I'm stuck on trying to output the form's success message since wffm mvc does not have Form.SuccessMessage(or as far as I know).

For webforms it's like this:`args.Result = args.Form.SuccessMessage + script;`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

datalayer where trigger on html element push using javascript. for example:
Your html element on show ,you want to push datalayer.

```
   $('#loading').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    dataLayer.push({ event: 'modalShowSuccessGoogleTy' });
});
```

ı hope this example can be helped you.